# Does H1 LED Bulb Fit in to existing H1 HID Bulb Projector?

Tags: headlight, led, hid

I have HID H1 6000K Bulb. Recently one of them gone bad. 
So, I'am Planning to replace the HID bulbs to H1 LED.

Question 1 : will LED h1 fit my existing H1 Projector? were i had Previously installed HID Bulbs.

Question 2 : Recommend some good H1 LED bulb Please.

Comment: Do a search for this topic on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are manufactured to regular specifications. It'll be even better.

I replace all bulbs in our cars to led the moment we get the car. These days majority of the bulbs in cars are LED, but still I end up changing a few since it's not all 100% led all round.

Get proper projected leds and put them in a good projected lens with a little adjusting it'll kill the competition. HID is just a waste of energy, too bright like the sun, but very difficult to guide it in a long beam. If what you say was true, are all the engineered leds a waste? Acura and Aston Martin are going all led with Hella MAtrix system. Mercedes and Audi have been doing this since 2012.

Personally on our SUVs I've got 3000K with projectors in head lamps, and fog lamps with 4000K. In our sedans good bright 6000K in all possible locations. And I've swapped out brake lights, blinkers, parking lights, safety lights, interior lights, dashboard, instrument cluster, HVAC, glove compartment with all 6000K bright and some even projected bulbs. It's all 100% white. Only the SUV lights at 3000K look yellow but bright and powerful

6000K is amazing in dry weather. 4200K is amazing all round. 3000K is solid for penetration power in horrible weather conditions.

Comment: I removed the down vote from your question. Someone down played your question.

Comment: Thanks much for the detail information. Planning to go and replace my hid to led. :)

Comment: When you do share pictures for us.

Comment: Will share once I replace them. Actually I'm looking to place an order via online. But not sure which brand is good.

Comment: Go with Samsung, cree or Phillips led with projected tip.

Comment: http://m.ebay.com/itm/H1-LED-SUPER-WHITE-LED-Fog-Light-Bulbs-Up-to-35W-Projector-w-11W-Chips-/161884813025?hash=item25b11636e1%3Ag%3A6YMAAOSweW5Vebsl&_trkparms=pageci%253A7fe66c9f-58bd-11e7-9817-74dbd18032f6%257Cparentrq%253Ad961643a15c0a7f8f41e0e08fffe7a20%257Ciid%253A3

Comment: Did you get any?

Comment: I've Ordered LED from Aliexpress. https://goo.gl/5xKNGr
will this fine ? i couldn't find Projected tip.

Comment: These are outdated. Buy the new 20000 lumen design. These will carry 3600 lumen per bulb.

Comment: Ho !! Can you gimme any links to go for ?

Comment: Email me at Eset@live.in